# mariadb - отсутствует /usr/share/mariadb/russian

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, lxc, dnf

В GNU Linux установил mariadb-server в lxc контейнере Fedora 28 amd64 командой `dnf install mariadb-server`, перед этим установил glibc-langpack-ru.

После установки и сравнения с хостовой машиной обнаружил отсутствие в `/usr/share/mariadb/` поддержки других языков, кроме английского
т.е. нет `/usr/share/mariadb/russian/`

Соответственно при входе в cli-mysql контейнера и выполнении `SET lc_messages = 'ru_RU';` получаю ошибку `ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'lc_messages' can't be set to the value of 'ru_RU'` 
На хосте эта же команда выполняется без ошибок, видимо по причине наличия `/usr/share/mariadb/russian/`.

UPD: в контейнере успешно выполняется `SET lc_messages = 'en_US';`

Из-за этой ошибки например не работает phpMyAdmin.

Вывод rpm -qf на хосте:
`rpm -qf /usr/share/mariadb/russian/errmsg.sys
mariadb-errmsg-10.3.10-1.fc29.x86_64`

В контейнере
`rpm -qf /usr/share/mariadb/english/errmsg.sys
mariadb-errmsg-10.2.18-1.fc28.x86_64`

Т.е. пакет фактически один и тот же, но разворачивается в зависимости от окружения по разному.

Вывод locale на хосте и контейнере не отличается.

UPD2: Вывод `rpm --showrc | grep lang`

Хост `-13: _install_langs   all
-13: find_lang  %{_rpmconfigdir}/find-lang.sh %{buildroot}
-13: go_arches  %{golang_arches} %{gccgo_arches}
-13: golang_arches  %{ix86} x86_64 %{arm} aarch64 ppc64le s390x
-- add golang prefix
goname       = "golang-" .. goname
-- golang-foo-foo-bar-foo names`

Контейнер: `-13: _install_langs C:en:en_US:en_US.UTF-8
-13: find_lang  %{_rpmconfigdir}/find-lang.sh %{buildroot}`

**С чем это может быть связано?**

UPD3: **решение** для указанного выше lxc контейнера
удалить файл `/etc/rpm/macros.image-language-conf`
переустановить пакет `dnf reinstall mariadb-errmsg`

Comment: приложите к вопросу вывод `$ rpm --showrc | grep lang` на обеих системах

Comment: @alexanderbarakin готово

Comment: @alexanderbarakin благодарю за наводку, нашёл причину, в контейнере `/etc/rpm/macros.image-language-conf` содержал `%_install_langs C:en:en_US:en_US.UTF-8`, на хосте такого файла нет! После зачистки и `dnf reinstall mariadb-errmsg` языки появились, команда смены языка в mysql выполняется успешно.

Comment: вы это в виде ответа оформите, пожалуйста.

Comment: доп. информация: [1](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-keyboard_configuration#s2-Locales_With_Kickstart) и [2](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/73986/how-can-i-install-all-locales/)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin думаю у Вас лучше получиться правильно оформить ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

контейнер, который вы используете, вероятно, подготовлен с «глубокими оптимизациями» ([например](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-keyboard_configuration#s2-Locales_With_Kickstart)).

в частности, программа *rpm* сконфигурирована не распаковывать файлы/каталоги, помеченные как «языковые» (кроме как для английского языка). приведён вывод для контейнера с `hub.docker.com`:

```
$ grep -r install_langs /etc/rpm/
/etc/rpm/macros.image-language-conf:%_install_langs en_US
```

можно в этом файле добавить русский:

```
%_install_langs en_US:ru
```

или вообще все языки:

```
%_install_langs all
```

или вообще удалить эту строку из файла `/etc/rpm/macros.image-language-conf` (да и вместе с файлом, если в нём больше ничего нет): по умолчанию будет как раз значение `all`.

и уже после этого устанавливать пакет *mariadb-server*. а если он уже установлен, достаточно переустановить пакет с (локализованными) сообщениями:

```
$ sudo dnf reinstall mariadb-errmsg
```

---

благодаря чему происходит эта «магия»? благодаря тому, что в [spec-файле](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/mariadb/blob/master/f/mariadb.spec#_1255), из которого собран (в т.ч. и) пакет *mariadb-errmsg*, каталоги с переводами сообщений упомянуты в макросе `%lang(язык)`:

```
...
%files errmsg
...
%lang(ru) %{_datadir}/%{pkg_name}/russian
...
```

«языковая» метаинформация сохраняется внутри пакета. посмотреть (для установленного пакета) можно, например, так:

```
$ rpm -q --queryformat="[%{FILELANGS} %{FILENAMES}\n]" mariadb-errmsg
...
ru /usr/share/mariadb/russian
ru /usr/share/mariadb/russian/errmsg.sys
...
```